# Error message related to package list being shown frequently on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: updates, configuration, system, gnome-shell-extension

To the best of my knowledge these errors are because of either 2 gnome-shell extensions or virtualbox. I have removed both now but still getting the problems maybe they have corrupted system configuration. Is there any way to fix it?

Now I don't know what's going but I haven't received a single snap update for quite few days.

[image: These are two of errors]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove problematic local software lists and install updates by using commands below:

```
sudo rm -v /var/lib/dpkg/lock* /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm -vrf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f -y
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

To update Snaps use

```
sudo snap refresh
```

Comment: If I use "sudo rm -v /var/lib/dpkg/lock* /var/cache/apt/archives/lock" won't I lose packages without knowing what I am removing?

Comment: Yes, they are safe commands.

Comment: I did whatever you've asked but again after a few days the error message is appearing.

Comment: The please run `sudo apt-get update` and add its output to question.

Comment: manual update checking works it's just the auto updates which sometimes doesn't work and shows error.

Comment: Actually what the problem that I think occurring is that whenever a new update arrives the software updater screen is appearing automatically and hence such problems are shown.