# Error: Opening the Cache on ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, error-handling

I have been getting an error of opening the cache as in the below photo on ubuntu.

[image: picture]

I have tried by deleting the lists directory and then doing sudo apt update, sudo apt upgrade. The problem did go for a day but the problem again arised. I didn't get the reason  for it. If someone knows a solution to it please share!!

Comment: I'd switch to another mirror; I've seen a few issues reported when people use `ubuntu-archive.mirrors.estointernet.in` on here ; https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors - this is who you're using https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/ubuntu-archive.mirrors.estointernet.in-archive

Comment: I already have tried the process as given in the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352185/error-message-related-to-package-list-being-shown-frequently-on-ubuntu-20-04) you have given but the problem came again after a day.